# "Valid date is required for date_1" error while using drupal_form_submit()

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

Field : **field_date_1** 
Type : **Date** 
Widget : **Pop-up calendar**
The settings for date field is as shown in 2 images

[image]
[image]

I get the values of a form_state into the $source_node and move that to $fs variable.The $source_node has date field stored as follows :

```
 [field_pt_date_1] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
        (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 2010-08-27 00:00:00
                            [timezone] => America/Phoenix
                            [timezone_db] => America/Phoenix
                [date_type] => datetime
                        )
             )
```

)

```
 $fs['values']['field_date_1']['und'][0]['value'] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($source_node->field_date_1['und'][0]['value']));
  $fs['values']['field_date_1']['und'][0]['timezone'] = $source_node->field_date_1['und'][0]['timezone'];
  $fs['values']['field_date_1']['und'][0]['timezone_db'] = $source_node->field_date_1['und'][0]['timezone_db'];
  $fs['values']['field_date_1']['und'][0]['date_type'] = $source_node->field_date_1['und'][0]['date_type'];
```

.........
The errors I am getting after executing the above code is as follows :

**A valid date is required for date_1.**

```
 drupal_form_submit('form_id', $fs, $source_node);
  $errors = form_get_errors();
```

And when checked the $errors variable I get

```
$errors = Array
(
 [field_date_1][und][0][value] => A valid date is required for <em class="placeholder">date_1</em>.
)
```

Comment: `date('m/d/Y', strtotime($source_node->field_date_1['und'][0]['value']));` why this conversion instead of the actual value ?

Comment: I had same code in D6 where it used the above date conversion and a comment was left that error will be produced while executing the drupal_execute() in D6 .So  I made the changes.. Also I have tried by directly placing the value but it still gives me error. Pls help . I want that this issue be solved by the end of day.

Comment: When I use node_save() I dont get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar kind of problem with drupal_form_submit.

After spending too much time following solution is working for me

```
    $datetime = $source_node->field_date_1['und'][0]['value'] ;
    $form_state['values']['field_date_1']['und'][0]['value'] = array(
      'date' => date('d/m/Y', strtotime($datetime)),
      'time' => date('h:ia', strtotime($datetime)),
    );
```

Hope it will help someone

Comment: Weird that it is not mentioned anywhere in document. Ideally I would expect a function by the module that takes care of this.